# Android custom seekbar

Tags: android, seekbar

I want to create a custom seek bar,I need to put an image in progressDrawable. However, on large screens , image is repeating .How can i  fill this image.Thanks for your solutions.

this is ss of my view
[image: http://s11.postimg.org/43wdr6xhf/seekbar.png]

this is my layer list

```
<item
        android:id="@+android:id/SecondaryProgress"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/feelingl"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/whitebg"/>
```

this is my seek bar;

```
 <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:max="100"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:progress="0"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom2"
            android:rotation="180"
            android:thumb="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you don't want this image to repat so try this `android:tileMode="disabled"`